# $\log_{3}\frac{16^{x-3}+14}{4^{x-3}+2}=243$ , find the value of $x$.

Tags: logarithms, contest-math

$\log_{3}\frac{16^{x-3}+14}{4^{x-3}+2}=243=3^5$
$\Rightarrow \frac{16^{x-3}+14}{4^{x-3}+2}= {3^3}^5=3^{243}$

I am not able to proceed from here. Please help !!!

The options given for this problem are :-

- $x$ is a rational number.
- $x$ is a natural number.
- $x$ is an even natural number.
- $x$ is a rational number less than $0$.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: $3^{3^5} \neq 3^{15}$

Comment: @BeKind : Isn't ${(a^m)}^n = a^{mn}$?

Comment: @Ganit : What you have here is $a^{m^n}$ NOT $(a^{m}) ^{n}$. $a^{m^n} =a^{(m^n)}$.

Comment: @sadman-ncc : Sorry ! I recognised my mistake. I have made the correction.

Comment: Additionally, what exactly do you mean by a _rough_ value of $x$ ?

Comment: @sadman-ncc : As per the options available for this question, it is not asking for the exact value of $x$. We just have to figure out what kind of number is $x$.

Comment: @Ganit Setting $y = 4^{x-3}$, then since $16^{x-3} = (4^2)^{x-3} = 4^{2(x-3)} = (4^{x-3})^2 = y^2$, you can create & solve a quadratic equation for $y$ and, from that, determine what the up to $2$ values of $x$ could be (or, at least, what type(s) of value(s) it might be since that is all the question is asking for). Nonetheless, this might not necessarily be the fastest & simplest way to solve the problem.

Comment: @JohnOmielan : I thought of that way as well but it is turning out to be this big chunky equation which I am not able to solve as well : $y^2-3^{243}y+(14-2.3^{243})= 0$

Comment: The key here isn't to solve for $y$. It's to eliminate options, most likely. Finding $x$ is most likely the job of the quadratic equation, but I don't think we need to go that far, there is something easier that can be used to eliminate options (I think). (By the way, do you have a source for this question?)

Comment: @JohnOmielan. What is funny is that the first iterate of Newton method gives the exact solution. Guess what is $x_0$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't know what $x_0$ is. However, I know that $4^{x-3}$ is quite close to $3^{243}$, so $x$ would be approximately $243\log_{4}(3) + 3 \approx 195.57$.

Comment: Let $3^{243}=a$, $4^{x-3}=y$, then $\frac{y^2+14}{y+2}=a$, $y^2+14=ay+2a$ , $y^2-ay+(14-2a)=0$. This is quadratic equation with respect to $y$. $D=a^2-4(14-2a)=a^2+8a-56$. $(a+3)^2=a^2+6a+9<D<a^2+8a+16=(a+4)^2$, then $a+3<\sqrt{D}<a+4$, then $\sqrt{D}$ is irrational. For real $x$, $y$ must be positive, then we consider only positive root for $y$ which is $\frac{a+\sqrt{D}}{2}$, then $y$ is irrational, then $x$ is not integer. But I suppose $x$ is also not rational.

Answer (score 4):

Note that, for $x = 5$, the LHS of $\frac{16^{x-3}+14}{4^{x-3}+2}$ becomes $\frac{256+14}{16+2}=15$, with the LHS being less than $15$ for $x \lt 5$ (with $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{16^{x-3}+14}{4^{x-3}+2}=\frac{14}{2} = 7$). Thus, $x \gt 5$. Also, we have that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{16^{x-3}+14}{4^{x-3}+2} & = \frac{16(16^{x-4})+14}{4(4^{x-4})+2} \\
& = \frac{8(16^{x-4})+7}{2(4^{x-4})+1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

If $x$ is an integer, then since $8(16^{x-4})+7 \equiv 7 \pmod{8}$ and $2(4^{x-4})+1 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, the fraction in \eqref{eq1A} also being an integer (i.e., $3^{243}$) means it's congruent to $7$ modulo $8$. However, since $3^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, we instead have $3^{243} \equiv 3(3^{242}) \equiv 3(3^2)^{121} \equiv 3 \pmod{8}$.

This contradiction shows $x$ can't be an integer. Thus, it must either be a positive irrational or a non-integer rational. Since none of the provided second to fourth options are valid possibilities, this means the first option must be the correct one, i.e., $x$ is a non-integral rational number.

Comment: Exactly. Basically, there's no need to solve the differential equation : some handwaving approximations will do the trick and eliminate the bad options.

Comment: Nice use of the contradiction !

Comment: I somehow managed to call this a differential equation above : no, it's a quadratic equation, and I beg furiously for a grand pardon.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer As far as I'm concerned, there's no need for a grand pardon, but since you "beg furiously" for one, it's granted!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$  starts from $-\infty$ and jumps only on integers waits at $0$ and again starts journey towards $\infty$

Let,
$$f(x) = \frac {16^{x-3} + 14}{4^{x -3} + 2}$$
$$\implies \log_3  \frac {16^{x-3} + 14}{4^{x -3} + 2} = L(x) = \log_3(f(x))$$

- $x\in (-\infty, 0)$

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) = 7 \text{ so also the value of }L(x\to-\infty) \to \text{some constant number}$$
Let me interpret this as the derivative of $L(x)$ should tend to $0$ as the value of $x\to-\infty$ or $\color{blue}{\text{Should we say this as the value of $L(x)$ is not changing as values of $x$ does?}} $

- $x=0$
  $f(0) \approx 7$ which is far enough to not to expect $L(0) = 243$
- $x\in (0, \infty)$

Lets write a function: $\lambda(x)$ = $\text{last digit function giving you the last digit of $x$}$

$$\begin{align}
\\ \lambda(3^2)=9
\\ \lambda(3^3)=7
\\ \lambda(3^4)=1
\\ \lambda(3^5)=3
\\
\\
\\ \implies \lambda(3^{243}) = 7
\end{align}$$

similarly
$$\lambda(L(i)) = \frac {\lambda(16^{i-3})+14}{\lambda(4^{i-3})+ 2} = \frac {\text{something ending with zero}}{\text{something ending with 6 or 8}} \ne \text{something ending with 7}$$
$x \notin \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Sorry but I do not know if this kind of informal proofs are accepted anywhere over to this I know a very less about formal proofs!
What I wrote is just something that made me sense which I think should not be regarded as the solution.